# Javascript async function basic

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

First of all I am new to `async` functions. Where is the problem in this code? I just get `test 1` and `test 2` output.

```
let isAvailable = false;

console.log('test1');

let asynchFunc = () => {
   return new Promise(() => {
       if (isAvailable === true) {
           console.log('here asyncFunc');
       }
   });
}

(async () => {
   await asynchFunc();
});

console.log('test2');

isAvailable = true;
```

Comment: A promise is no good if you never resolve or reject it

Comment: "*Where is the problem?*" - we cannot know unless you tell us what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i say it in a better way:

If you add a `timeout` inside the promise, `isAvailable = true` instruction will get executed before reaching the check on this variable, otherwise, `isAvailable` will remain `false`.

You can test both cases below

#### Without timeout

```js
let isAvailable = false;

console.log('test1');

let asynchFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isAvailable === true) {
      console.log('here asyncFunc');
      resolve('has been available');
    } else {
      reject('still not available')
    }
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    let res = await asynchFunc();
    console.log(res);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();

console.log('test2');

isAvailable = true;
```

#### With Timeout

```js
let isAvailable = false;

console.log('test1');


let asynchFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (isAvailable === true) {
        console.log('here asyncFunc');
        resolve('has been available');
      } else {
        reject('still not available')
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}

(async () => {
  try {
    let res = await asynchFunc();
    console.log(res);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();

console.log('test2');

isAvailable = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to call the async function like this?

```
(async () => {
   await asynchFunc();
})();
```

(Note the added `()` at the end)

I'm not sure what you're trying to test here, the async function will still see the `false` value. You can see that by changing your function to:

```
let asynchFunc = () => {
   return new Promise(() => {
         console.log('check isavailable:', isAvailable);
   });
}
```

If you're just looking for a setup that will let you play around with async functions then you can use this code:

```
const sleep = (time) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));

let isAvailable = false;

(async () => {
  console.log('isAvailable:', isAvailable);
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log('isAvailable:', isAvailable);
})();

console.log('test2');

isAvailable = true;
```

Just be aware that using a sleep function like this to wait for something to be available is completely the wrong way of doing things. You should never have an `isAvailable` flag, the value should just be a promise that will resolve once it's available. What language are you coming from? What is your actual issue? We can help you better with real world problems.

Comment: I actually expect the if statement to work when the isAvailable comes true

Comment: That's not how it works I'm afraid. Your async function will run immediately and still see that isAvailable is false.

Comment: ow yes I got it now

Answer (score 0):

```js
let isAvailable = false;

console.log('test1');

let asyncFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (isAvailable === true) {
        resolve('here asyncFunc');
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}

(async() => {
  return await asyncFunc(); // await used here is optional
})().then(v => {
  console.log(v);  // prints value after 2 seconds.
});

console.log('test2');
isAvailable = true;
```

All `Promises` need to be either resolved or rejected. In your case you did neither. In order to see the value in the async function, I passed the value to the `resolve` callback.

> In an async function it is optional to use the `await` key when returning a value as the return value of an `async function` is implicitly wrapped in `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.then` and `.catch` inside an async function, it kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: but i was expecting like this test1 - test2 - here asyncFunc

Comment: But setTimeout works with promise. Why didn't work the other one?

Comment: Have you checked my answer? `setTimeout` is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function you can play around with that might help you understand what's going on a bit more. Note you're using a immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) to switch from synchronous to asynchronous code, which is fine as long as you understand that `console.log('test2')` in your original code may not process in the same order as your code looks like it might. However, you did not call the IIFE, so simply add () to the end of it.

I.e.,

```
(function (){})();
(()=>{})();
(async function(){})();
(async ()=>{})();
```

As for the rest of your code, you don't resolve or reject your promise, return the promise correctly from the function, and you need to try{}catch{} your asynchronous function otherwise reject() from the promise will be unhandled.

```
(function(){      
    let isAvailable = false;
    let asynchFunc = () => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if (isAvailable === true) {
            console.log('Available');
            resolve(true);
        }else{
            console.log('Not available');
            reject(false)
        }
    });
    (async () => {
        try{
            // isAvailable = true; // test with me.
            console.log('test1');
            // result is always true, unless there is an error.
            // but if there is an error 
            // the rejected promise will go to catch(e){}.
            let result = await asynchFunc(); 
            console.log('test2');
            isAvailable = true;
        }catch(e){
            console.log('Error:',e)
        }
    })();  
})();
```